# C - ssprintf() unable to retrieve a substring from the string

Tags: c, cgi

I have a CGI script (C program `test.c`/`test.elf`) that reads from the enviromental variable `QUERY_STRING` this string `login_email=example%40my.com&login_password=my_pass` which consists of expressions `login_email=example%40my.com` and `login_password=my_pass` sepparated with `&`.

I need to extract only the variable values `example%40my.com` and `my_pass` but because function `strtok()` is destructive I want to use `sscanf()` to do this.

I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char env_arr[1000];
    char* env_arr_ptr;
    env_arr_ptr = &env_arr[0];

    printf("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n");

    env_ptr = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    strcpy(env_arr_ptr, env_ptr);

    printf("%s: %s<br>", "Value of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", env_arr);
    printf("%s: %p<br>", "Address of the \"QUERY_STRING\"", env_ptr);

    char login_email_arr[60] = "";
    char login_password_arr[60] = "";

    sscanf(env_ptr, "login_email=%s&login_password=%s", login_email_arr, login_password_arr); // removed "_ptr" at the end of arguments
    printf("login_email: %s<br>", login_email_arr);
    printf("login_password : %s<br>", login_password_arr);


}
```

But when I call the CGI script with my browser using the GET method the script returns this:

[image]

It seems I am doing something wrong with a `sscanf()`. It starts reading my first value `example%40my.com` at the right place, but it doesn't stop at `&` and the first value becomes `example%40my.com&login_password=my_pass` and nothing is left for my second value which remains empty.

How could I extract both variables?

Comment: Umm... that's *so wrong* on *so many levels*. I do not even know where to start, but writing a CGI script in C is the first mistake. If you do any mistakes (like you did here) a remote attacker can control your device in no time.

Comment: `sscanf` is absolutely the **worst** tool to use to scan a query string; and you do not need to copy the query string around, because it can e longer than 1000 characters, and you're not checking for buffer overflows...

Comment: First thing to note about `sscanf` is that it does not do *any kind of pattern matching*, it has just one character lookahead. `%s` means "space-delimited word* and since you do not have any spaces in your first parameter, you're going to get everything. Read the answer to the linked to question, but again, you should consider whether writing CGI in C is sane **at all**.

Comment: Ok this is what I was suspecting. Thank you. What do you suggest? I really don't want to use `strtok()`...

Comment: Just read the *answer* to the question I've linked to. Ok, it uses `strtok`, you can use `strtok_r` instead. There are really not many QA on parsing the query string on stack overflow in C, because it is ... not really a good idea